# Git Committing/Merging shows in logs but not in repo

Tags: git, github, merge, conflict, repo

So I'm working solo on a remote branch. I've encountered an issue where I made a commit & merge, but it won't show up in my repository. I've been using the same commands that worked just fine before, but for some reason, git showed a "recursive merge" log when making my merge this time. All my commits/merge show in "git log -a", but the repository isn't updated whatsoever.

```
git status (checked all unadded files)
git add <files> (added each file I wanted to update)
git commit -m <message>
git merge origin <remote branch>
```

Then I received the recursive merge log even though I had never seen it before when using these same steps. Any idea on what is occurring here and how I fix it so I can merge it to my repo?

`git log -a` results: (Redacted some of it)

```
commit 0c3e6db87ef65a461fae4400f3b6d5d9a3XXXXX (HEAD -> <remote branch>)
Merge: 6d3c9107b 70cXXXXX
Date:   Mon Jan 25 15:54:21 2021 -0800
 
    <message>
 
commit 6d3c9107b39a70629a82e080c3ccc5ceebXXXXX
Merge: eccc05826 6daXXXXX
Date:   Mon Jan 25 15:44:03 2021 -0800
 
    Merge remote-tracking branch 'Origin' into <remote branch>
 
commit eccc05826910208fc0b4e4aae061a416b4XXXXX
Date:   Mon Jan 25 15:42:57 2021 -0800

  <message>
```

EDIT: I haven't done `git push` but would there be a problem if I have two commits on my log?

Comment: Note that `HEAD` never points to a remote-tracking name: it can be *detached*, and not point to a name at all but rather directly to a commit; or it can be attached to a (local) branch name. I think you've damaged your diff slightly during your redaction.

Answer (score 1):

`git log` only shows you what's in the repo. If you want those commits in some other repo, maybe the one github's hosting for you, push or fetch them there, or use some of the other lower-level methods for more constrained environments.

Comment: Totally forgot to push it, shows how silly I am. Thanks!

Comment: I have never been that silly. You believe me, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

If you try **git push** that should push it to the repository.